# How to notify the owner to undelete the answer?

Tags: support, vote-to-undelete

I've ask this question: [Directive that include page where TemplateUrl is created from an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968981/directive-that-include-page-where-templateurl-is-created-from-an-attribute) someone answer, I've commented, that something was not working and the person delete the answer, but then I try it again with latest version of the library and it work, which mean that this was the right answer.

How can I notify the owner of that answer that he should undelete it because he was right? I've edited the answer (the only thing I can do with deleted question) and put message that he should undelete, in hope that he will see notification, but the answer still remain deleted.

The user have 4,569 points, don't know if that matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answerer has a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968981/directive-that-include-page-where-templateurl-is-created-from-an-attribute#comment35075509_22968981) on your question. You can reply to that comment and ask to un-delete the answer.

[image]

Comment: Didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to ping the user on that specific answer since it was already deleted.  You could comment on one of their other answers to try to get their attention or reply to [their other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968981/directive-that-include-page-where-templateurl-is-created-from-an-attribute#comment35075509_22968981) on your question.

I've gone ahead an undeleted the answer for you since you stated this solved your problem.